# There exist integers $x,y$ such that $(x,y)=g, [x,y]=l$ iff $g|l$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is similar to an exercise I just posted.  The necessary part is easy, but the sufficient condition I'm having trouble seeing.

$\Rightarrow$.  Since $(x,y)=g,$ there exist integers $x_1, y_1$ such that $x=gx_1, y=gy_1$.  Since $[x,y]=l$, there exist integers $x_2, y_2$ such that $l=xx_2=yy_2$.  Then
$$l=gx_1x_2=gy_1y_2$$
In both cases, $g|l$

$\Leftarrow$.  Since $g|l$, there exists an integer $k$ such that $l=gk$.  Since $k$ is an integer, there exist integers $k_1, k_2$ such that $k=k_1+k_2$.  Then 
$$l=gk_1+gk_2 $$
$$gk=gk_1+gk_2$$
I feel like I'm not even close....  any hints?

Comment: $(x,y)$ is GCD and $[x,y]$ is LCM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $x=g$ and let $y=l$. (We do need to assume that $l\gt 0$ and $g\ge 0$.)

Comment: Really?  That's it?  l is a multiple of g and g is a divisor of l, so setting x=g and y=1 and taking (l,g) and [l,g] finishes the proof?

Comment: Yes, that/s all there is to it, apart from the minor necessary assumptions about positivity.

Comment: Thank you.  Sometimes the simplest explanations are not even given a thought, and when they are finally shown, one can feel really gullible...

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, it is a little disappointing when it turns out to be simple.

Comment: @Lalaloopsy One way to make it obvious is to think about from an order-theoretic (lattice) perspective - see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{eqnarray}{\bf Hint}\quad\ g\mid \ell &\iff&\!\!\! (g,\,\ell)\, =\, g\quad\  &\rm or&\ \quad g\le \ell &\!\iff&\!\! g\wedge\ell\, =\, g\quad\text{in lattice language}  \\
&\iff&\!\!\! {\bf [\,}g,\,\ell\,{\bf ]}\, =\, \ell\ \ \  & &\ \ \ \ \phantom{g\le \ell} &\!\iff&\!\! g\vee\ell\, =\, \ell \end{eqnarray}$

**Remark** $\ $ This is obvious if one views it from a [lattice-theoretic perspective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_%28order%29#Connection_between_the_two_definitions) (see this [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple#Lattice-theoretic) for that viewpoint). You may find it instructive to generalize the problem to lattices.